# Local host isnt working as soon as i include smarty file....MAMP

Tags: smarty

i have installed php storm ide, now i have download smarty, and followed this tutorial

https://memohnish.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/smarty-installation-on-wamp-and-xampp/

now i have created a test project in PHP storm, then created a php file.

As soon as i include a smarty file, browser shows an error[image]

[image]

[image]

i have tried everything, nothing works, previously i have used the same method and everything used to work fine. Now, browser shows error.

second image shows php.ini file, please tell me if there is any error....

i have included the smarty libs directory as well.

dont know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the php file just before requiring Smarty and you probably will be able to see the problem description

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```